# BIM server Database Access

Tags: java, ifc, bim

I am a Java developer. Recently my company is planning to use BIM Server .
Concept is , BIM server will be integrated with our current project and we will access the BIM Server database through some API . I made connectivity with localhost BIM server , created project and add IFC files under the project using "JsonBimServerClientFactory" (Example provided in BIM server's git repository). Is there any one in the group who has this kind of experience ?

I am in great confusion, how I should use the API's to get access into BIM Server database from my existing project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bimserver team provides a REST API and a java client library.  You can communicate with either of those methods.

You cannot access the database directly without building a BerkelyDB connector but the api's interfaces should suffice (specifically the ServiceInterface and the LowLevelInterface)

Some helpful links:
[BimServer -- Client Library and Server](https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMserver/releases)
[BimServerGUI -- Useful GUI Plugin](https://github.com/opensourceBIM/bimvie.ws/releases)

Comment: @Nazar-E-Bukhari this answer seems to be correct for your question. Please mark it.

Comment: but how do i use it with a java application? the plugin is a javascript and i have a java desktop application

Comment: There is a java client in each release. 
 https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMserver/wiki/BimServerClient

Comment: yes i can use this to get all sorts of information and i have also done some part of it, but i am not sure how do i make a 3D view just like bimviews which is in java script, could i embed the existing plugin to java app? i am sorry for asking such type of question but i am very confused.