# Integration of BIM Server with Java based web application

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am completely new in BIM sever related project. I have a project to develop a module for real state industry to monitor the model efficiently in java based web application. A brief description as follows :
Suppose we build a mall. There is some 3d model will be designed by designer. I have to visualize the model in the browser. If any modification is/are needed then the different stakeholder can comment on it or mark it. Then the designer will resolve it. The updated model should be visualized to all the stakeholder. The history should be maintained so that anyone can see the diff in the different release.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want some help regarding integration of BIM Server to my web application developed in java technologies.

Comment: Your question is similar to this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240508/bim-server-database-access